# Avoiding the new upsert in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, upsert, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

Steve Marx writes about new extension methods to perform upserts in Azure Table Storage as part of the new storage protocol version here:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/extension-methods-for-the-august-storage-features

However, what if I want to do the original operation of unconditional-merge-or-throw, rather than an upsert. I want to merge an object, updating a single field, but throw if the entity doesn't exist rather than create a new entity that contains only the properties I'm merging.

Is this possible? Note that I want to use upsert elsewhere, so I've taken to having IoC provide me with contexts created from `GetDataServiceContext2011` instead of `GetDataServiceContext`. I suppose I could alternate between the two, but that won't help when the Azure team updates the official libraries.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452241.aspx):

> The Insert Or Merge Entity operation uses the MERGE verb and must be
>   called using the 2011-08-18 version or newer. In addition, it does not
>   use the If-Match header. These attributes distinguish this operation
>   from the Update Entity operation, though the request body is the same
>   for both operations.

So, how do I get the storage library to emit a wildcard `If-Match` on save rather than emit no `If-Match` at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `AttachTo` with an asterisk for an etag. That will result in an `If-Match: *`. Here's a complete working example:

```
class Entity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Entity() { }
    public Entity(string rowkey) : base(string.Empty, rowkey) { }
}
class Program
{
    static void Update(CloudStorageAccount account)
    {
        var ctx = account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetDataServiceContext();

        var entity = new Entity("foo") { Text = "bar" };
        ctx.AttachTo("testtable", entity, "*");
        ctx.UpdateObject(entity);
        ctx.SaveChangesWithRetries();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(args[0]);
        var tables = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        tables.CreateTableIfNotExist("testtable");
        var ctx = tables.GetDataServiceContext();

        try { Update(account); } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Exception (as expected): " + e.Message); }

        ctx.AddObject("testtable", new Entity("foo") { Text = "foo" });
        ctx.SaveChangesWithRetries();

        try { Update(account); } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception: " + e.Message); }

        Console.WriteLine("Now text is: " + tables.GetDataServiceContext().CreateQuery<Entity>("testtable").Where(e => e.PartitionKey == string.Empty && e.RowKey == "foo").Single().Text);
        tables.DeleteTableIfExist("testtable");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of feel dumb on this one. :-P

Comment: @smarx what does the etag actually do? I tried to google up on it but did not find any explanation to it.

Comment: @starcom In this case, the question itself gives the answer and provides the source (MSDN).